Plugin “@netlify/plugin-nextjs” failed on React project
Good evening. I have a React project ( https://404projectschool.netlify.app/ ) and when i try to deploy it on netlify.com i get this error:
Netlify Build

8:56:08 PM: ​
8:56:08 PM: ❯ Using Next.js Runtime - v4.41.3
8:56:08 PM: ​
8:56:08 PM: ❯ Loading plugins
8:56:08 PM: - @netlify/plugin-lighthouse@6.0.0 from Netlify app
8:56:08 PM: ​
8:56:08 PM: ❯ Outdated plugins
8:56:08 PM: - @netlify/plugin-nextjs@4.41.3: latest version is 5.3.2
8:56:08 PM: To upgrade this plugin, please uninstall and re-install it from the Netlify plugins directory (Netlify App)
8:56:10 PM: No Next.js cache to restore.
8:56:10 PM: ​
8:56:10 PM: build.command from netlify.toml
8:56:10 PM: ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
8:56:22 PM: ​
8:56:22 PM: Error message
8:56:22 PM: Error: The directory “/opt/build/repo/build” does not contain a Next.js production build. Perhaps the build command was not run, or you specified the wrong publish directory.
8:56:22 PM: In most cases it should be set to “.next”, unless you have chosen a custom “distDir” in your Next config.
8:56:22 PM: If you are using “next export” then you should set the environment variable NETLIFY_NEXT_PLUGIN_SKIP to “true”.
8:56:22 PM: ​
8:56:22 PM: Plugin details
8:56:22 PM: Package: @netlify/plugin-nextjs
8:56:22 PM: Version: 4.41.3
8:56:22 PM: Repository: git+https://github.com/netlify/next-runtime.git
8:56:22 PM: npm link: @netlify/plugin-nextjs - npm
8:56:22 PM: Report issues: Issues · netlify/next-runtime · GitHub
8:56:22 PM: ​
8:56:22 PM: Error location
8:56:22 PM: In “onBuild” event in “@netlify/plugin-nextjs” from Netlify app


my netlify.toml file is:
[build]
command = “npm run build”
publish = “build”

I deleteed everything related to next and nextjs.
